# Looking for more data on a vampire novel named *Fourteen* including author

Tags: story-identification

There is a stub article on TVTropes.org for a work named *[Fourteen](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Fourteen)* (or maybe *14*). I've tried contacting the person who wrote the entry and tried searching for the provided details, but with no luck. Does anyone know whether this was an actual published book? One released on the web?

### Prologue quote

> "I was fourteen when I was abducted. Fourteen when I learned my true past. Fourteen when I met my dad for the first time. Fourteen when I woke, surrounded by dead bodies. Fourteen when I realized I had killed said dead bodies. Fourteen when I met Nate and Khloe. Fourteen when I ceased to be Sunni Russo. Fourteen when I became a hideous monster."
>   
> —Sunni Russo, prologue

### Plot Summary

> Yes, this is one of those vampire books. Sunni Russo is abducted from a grocery store and taken to a hotel, where she is changed into a vampire. After a week of sleeping, she awakens to find that she went on a rampage, and learns of her newfound thirst from friends, Nate and Khloe.

Comment: I don't think it exists.  Googling "Sunni Russo" and "vampire" only produces a link to the TV Tropes page you mentioned.

Comment: That's my suspicion too, but I've had other things where I didn't think the answer existed and this community has surprised me...

Comment: There is a series called "The Morganville Vampires", and the 14th volume is titled "The Fall of Night", but none of the character names match up.

Comment: The Peter Clines book also contains a character called Nate

Comment: {nods} But it has no vampires.

Comment: Sounds like a self-published writer adding mentions for a book that never ended up happening.